# Avoiding multiple Salesforce logins while extracting Records out of Salesforce using CLI data loader

Tags: data-loader

Current Scenario:
We have currently 6 beans for different objects extracts.
CLI Data loader calls each process-bean one by one there by logging into salesforce each time, and get extract out of SF.

Is there a way we can open the session for whole of the extract process and have a single Salesforce login to extract the Objects.

Pls suggest your Pointers or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Salesforce Data Loader** requires a configuration file to run in 'Batch Mode', this currently only takes a user name and password. As per the example [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line#The_files). I've scanned the full set of properties available in this configuration file for a SessionId/oAuth token (for example) and there is none. You can review for yourself [here](https://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/loader_params.htm).

CLI (or Batch Mode) supports multiple 'process runner beans' in the **process-conf.xml** file. It would assume that due to the behaviour your seeing it is not pooling the connections to the Salesforce server and making a fresh login for each process runner bean you define in this file? Certainly if you are not using multiple process configs it might be worth a try to see if it would, but I'm personally doubtful.

Sorry its not better news, it would seem the only way to optimise this further is to perhaps review other alternatives (though I'm personally not aware of any of the alternative ones giving a CLI) or write your own Java program using the [Salesforce API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm). In some cases I've found this an easier route than (assuming you have coding skills) since you can make assumptions about your CSV files ([How to automate the loading and updating of reference data from command line/ant?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15072/how-to-automate-the-loading-and-updating-of-reference-data-from-command-line-ant)).

Comment: Yes, i had also checked all data loader PDFs and articles. No way to have a sinngle alive session. Only alternative is a custom java program.